# Can there be multiple Web.Config files in root folder

Tags: asp.net

We can configure the settings for the webpages in a particular folder by keeping single web.config. Can there be multiple web.config in a same hierarchy as i saw some where **web.config.debug** and **web.config.release** and **web.config**. Why they are intended for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx), which allow you to apply changes to different builds of your project (debug, dev, release, etc).

The ones suffixed with `.debug`, `.release`, etc, are the transformation files.  They take the base `web.config` and modify it using the XML-Document-Transform attributes you specify.

A classic use case is the `debug=true` attribute, which you never want to use in production.  You can use a simple transformation to remove it in your `web.config.release` file:

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <compilation debug="true" />
</configuration>
```

**Web.config.release**

```
<configuration>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
</configuration>
```